# How to use a function from a JavaScript package produced by GopherJS?

Tags: go, gopherjs

I have written a simple package in Go and I have compiled with gopherJS .

I have then included it my HTML via

`<script src="./testgopher.js">`

It has been loaded and all is well. But I am not sure how I can reuse a go function that has been declared in one of packages inside my own javascript.

What I want to do is in another script tag

```
<script> testpkg.Testfunc() </script>
```

where the testpkg and Testfunc have been written in go.

I tried to look into the window object and it doesnt look like the function has been added to window.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs#providing-library-functions-for-use-in-other-javascript-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to register your function if you want to call it from JavaScript. For that you may use the [`js.Global`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js#Global) variable.

Let's see a simple Go function called `Hello()` which writes the `"Hello World!"` text into the main document:

```
import "github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js"

func Hello() {
    js.Global.Get("document").Call("write", "Hello World!")
}
```

Then in your Go `main()` function you can register it like this:

```
func main() {
    js.Global.Set("Hello", Hello)
}
```

After this registration, the `"Hello"` identifier will be available to you in JavaScript. Since we registered a Go function value (`Hello`) to this identifier, it will also be a function in JavaScript which you can simply call like this:

```
<script>
    Hello();
</script>
```